# Como separar uma rota fixa de uma rota com variável com asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho um controle que administra videos. Estou tentando fazer esses dois metodos:

```js
[Route("video/categoria/{categoria}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string categoria)
{


}

[Route("video/categoria/new-movies")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{


}
```

Quando executa a url `/video/categoria/new-movies` ele cai na rota `[Route("video/categoria/{categoria}")]` colocando o valor `new-movies` dentro da variável categoria.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma dele cair na outra rota.

Se não existir, o mais indicado é tratar tudo no mesmo método mesmo?

Busco uma solução tecnicamente mais correta para evitar futuros problemas e facilitar a manutenção.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimente inverter os métodos:

```
[Route("video/categoria/new-movies")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{


}

[Route("video/categoria/{categoria}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string categoria)
{


}
```

Alternativamente, passo mais um método, que é configurando rotas no `RouteConfig`. A precedência começa sempre pela rota mais específica. A rota mais genérica deve ficar por último porque ela é resolvida por último.

```
namespace SeuProjeto
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "NovosFilmes",
                url: "video/categoria/new-movies",
                defaults: new { controller = "Videos", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Filmes",
                url: "video/categoria/{categoria}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Videos", action = "Index", categoria = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou e vou marcar como resposta, você poderia colocar como segunda sugestão a parte de como eu configuraria esse caso especifico, por favor?

Comment: Pronto. Agora está completo.

Comment: Obrigado! Ainda tem q esperar 5 min para marcar a reposta.

Comment: Tranquilo. Sem pressa.